# Shift values column and other corresponding columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame:

```
  Group  ID  Days Days1 
    1    3    0     7
    1    1    7     7
    1    7    11    7
    1    1    16    1
    2    2    0     7
    2    1    3     7
    2    9    9     7
    2    3    18    7
    2    5    21    7
    2    2    5     1
```

I want to convert this dataframe to;

Expected output:

```
      Group from ID  to ID Days Days1 
        1     3         1   7     7
        1     1         7   11    7
        1     7         1   16    1
        2     2         1   3     7
        2     1         9   9     7 
        2     9         3   18    7
        2     3         5   21    7 
        2     5         2   5     1
```

Where the ID column is switched to a 'from ID' and 'to ID'

'from ID' remains the same as ID column, while 'to ID' is shifted down one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html), then remove rows by `to ID` by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), convert column to integers and `rename`:

```
df['from ID'] = df.groupby('Group')['ID'].shift()
df = df.dropna(subset=['from ID']).astype({'from ID':int}).rename(columns={'ID': 'to ID'})
print (df)
   Group  to ID  Days  Days1  from ID
1      1      1     7      7        3
2      1      7    11      7        1
3      1      1    16      1        7
5      2      1     3      7        2
6      2      9     9      7        1
7      2      3    18      7        9
8      2      5    21      7        3
9      2      2     5      1        5
```

If order is important use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
df.insert(1, 'from ID',  df.groupby('Group')['ID'].shift())
df = df.dropna(subset=['from ID']).astype({'from ID':int}).rename(columns={'ID': 'to ID'})
print (df)
   Group  from ID  to ID  Days  Days1
1      1        3      1     7      7
2      1        1      7    11      7
3      1        7      1    16      1
5      2        2      1     3      7
6      2        1      9     9      7
7      2        9      3    18      7
8      2        3      5    21      7
9      2        5      2     5      1
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, use the pandas shift method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

the original dataframe:

[image]

I will shift the score column down by 1 and create a new column like this:

```
df['score1'] = df['score'].shift(-1)
df
```

Now the output would be:

[image]

You can see the column 'score1', here the 'score' column was shifted by one.

In your exact case, it would be:

```
df["to ID"] = df["from ID"].shift(-1)
```